# Colored overlay in WPF

Tags: wpf, canvas, overlay

I would like to draw some rectangle on top of certain area of a window in WPF application. The problem is how to do it in such way that during window's size change the figure gets resized proportionally too?
Any hints highly appreciated.

Comment: Can't you re-paint the rectangle by the ratio of new window coordinates?

Comment: `this.SizeChanged += (_, __) => {//do your calculations here and redraw the rectangle}`?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that in your window's code behind file:

```
//Constructor
public MyWindow() {

   InitializeComponent();

   //Register the SizeChanged-event
   this.SizeChanged += OnSizeChanged;
}

private void OnSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
   var parentWindow = (Window)sender;
   var sizeOfRectangle = CalculateSizeOfRectangle(parentWindow.actualHeight, parentWindow.actualWidth);

   // assuming you have a reference to your colored rectangle here (e.g. Name defined in XAML code)
   ColoredRectangle.Width = sizeOfRectangle.Width;
   ColoredRectangle.Height = sizeOfRectangle.Height;
}

private Size CalculateSizeOfRectangle(double height, double width)
{
    int height = ....; // Calculate height here
    int width = ....;  // Calculate width her
    return new Size(width, height);
}
```